# Reverse engineering unknown RS232/UART binary protocol

Tags: hardware, embedded, serial-communication, protocol

## Background story

For couple of days I'm trying to crack the protocol used the old medical device, in order to collect data for a research in an automated way.

The device in question is **Novametrix CO2SMO Plus**, model **8100**. Manufacturer of this device was bought, long time ago, by Respironics and than Respironcis was bought by Philips. Their website doesn't exists for last 12-14 years and archived copy doesn't have any useful information. Since device was designed before 2000 there's no software over the Internet - it was distributed on floppy disks so as software updates.

Device is very similar to model 7100, which was released ~3 years prior to the 8100. Devices mainly differ in software - the one in 8100 is much more sophisticated.

## Physical layer

At first I stared from obvious things like determining physical layer of the connection - that went easy, since [service manual](http://www.frankshospitalworkshop.com/equipment/documents/pulse_oximeter/service_manuals/Novametrix_8100_-_Service_manual.pdf) actually lists all signals in DB25, located on the back of the device.

At the beginning I hoped 8100 will use similar, well documented by manufacturer, ASCII protocol (called `NOVACOM1`) as 7100 used. Unfortunately it's not the case. My device uses newer protocol called `NOVACOM3` - there's zero information about it in the Internet; it seems like `NOVACOM2` was never released.

I don't own oscilloscope (and I don't have an access to electronics labs on my college), so I determined baudrate of the port just observing the traffic with different baudrates with debugging mode enabled on device (more on that later). With high confidence I can say it's 9600 8N1 (like in previous model).

Device uses [NXP MC68332 MCU](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/more-processors/coldfire-plus-coldfire-32-bit-mcus/68k-processors-legacy/m683xx/32-bit-microcontroller:MC68332), which according to the data sheet is a rugged 32 bit core with quite a few subunits useful in an automotive applications. It also seems to be a secure one - since I have almost no experience in EE I quickly dismissed any possibilities to attempt of physically attacking the CPU.

## PC software

According to the service manual, manufacturer had developed PC software used for communication with the device - *"CO2SMO Plus! for Windows"*. Unfortunately it was sold as a separate package and it's nowhere to be found now.

## Diagnostic protocol

The device has two Novametrix protocols - `NOVACOM3` and `SATDIAG`. Since diagnostic protocols are usually simpler I started from the later one:

- SATDIAG streams data continuously
- Protocol, besides sending data to the computer, contains some unknown upload mode for firmware update (probably some XMODEM or so... I don't have firmeware blob, so obviously I didn't played with this)
- After analysis I can say with high confidence each packet begins with `0x00` and ends with `0x0A` (LF)
- Protocol streams packets few times a second (I didn't conducted any measurements on that, but it's 15-20/s)
- Device alternates between sending 9 and 25 bytes (including 2B of header and footer) packets
- Every few of seconds 41 bytes packet is transmitted
- Most probably no checksum is used (the same payloads contain different last byte, I also calculated popular checksums for few)
- Protocol seems to be aimed strictly for collecting performance data, some sort of resources usage or represents unknown internal state -  changes in measurements aren't causing any notable changes in packets. I also tried manually searching for numbers similar to these displayed by the device - no luck.

In summary `SATDIAG` seems to be more like a debugger dumping some performance metrics or resources usage.

## Control protocol

Next I started playing with the protocol used to talk to the PC software - NOVACOM3:

- The protocol follows request-response pattern
- In order to display live waveforms protocol has to contain continuous mode which just streams data without additional queries: *that is what I want to get*
- By sending different characters I determined that `0x00` marks end of the packet. There's no signs of any character marking beginning the the packets.
- It looks like device expects (some?) packets to be 8 bytes (including trailing `NULL-BYTE`) long - while sending different lengths terminated by `0x00` I see for 8 bytes device is consistent with replying with 2 bytes.
- Seems to have no checksum - I've got different 2 bytes responses with the same first byte and different 2nd
- Response packets seems to have no length defined
- Sending multiple `0x00` seems to "zero" the device input buffer - while I was playing with determining length sending 3-4 `0x00` was causing device to behave consistently.
- Sending multiple `0x00` generates no response
- Protocol may have some blocks of commands: while I started scanning by sending 1 byte + `0x00` I've got no response for 7 bytes after each of the bytes: `0x10`, `0x30`, `0x50`, `0x70`, `0x90`, `0xb0`, `0xd0`, `0xf0`
- All responses which I was able to get were 2 bytes or 4 bytes (and the longer ones seem to be 2 packets actually). Each packet was started with `0x2A`
- The only responses o was able to get were: `{0x2A, 0xA0}`, `{0x2A, 0xA1}`, `{0x2A, 0x80}`
- The packet `{0x2A, 0x80}` may actually be some sort of ACK, since a lot of times I had to wait for second packet for a 1-1.5s when responses were 4 bytes long.
- `0x20` (space) / `0x40` (@) / `0x60` seems to be a white character - sending it followed by 0x00 leads to no response. These characters are also very common in SATDIAG.  It's a little bit suspicious that they're spaced so evenly 20-40-60. Now while writing this I think it might be some connection with the ranges described few points before (10-30-50-70-90-...)

## I'm stucked...

I wasn't able to force device to start streaming - if I would manage to do that figuring out parameters shouldn't be that hard, since I have the display on the unit and I know which parameters to expect. Until than... I have no idea how to progress further. I also tried contacting Philips division which bought the company - no response whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Comment: are the flash chips soldered or socketed? I would suggest dumping them to extract the firmware, from which you can RE the protocol details.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky: I just opened the device. Besides the fact it's built like a tank everything is in sockets (even polyfuses!). It has two 2Mbit AT29C020-12JC memory chips, and according to ten service manual they're both occupied by the software. However I have no idea how to read them (without breaking the bank) nor how to analyze the software for this CPU.

Comment: I found out your question while searching for the CO2SMO protocol. In the next few days, I will try and run it with the original software, while running a serial data logger in the computer. Then I will check the results, and maybe we can crack the protocol together. Cheers
Antonio